# In sending HTTPS request using Javax webtarget client, how to avoid encoding of query params that contain ":["?

Tags: java, jax-rs, urlencode, urldecode

I am using WebTarget to send a GET request with query params.

This is my expected request that I need to generate:

```
{{host}}/svc/lookupservice/v2/findItems?filter=creationdate:[2020-05-01T00:08:17.000Z..]&limit=25&offset=0&userType=seller&userid=11234567
```

But using webtarget as follows:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
...
...
class A {
    private Client client;

  public void apiCall(String userId, String startDate, String endDate) {
    String endpoint = (String)this.client.getConfiguration().getProperty("jaxrs.client.endpointuri");
    WebTarget webTarget = this.client.target(endpoint).path("/lookupservice/v2/findItems")
              .queryParam("userType", new Object[]{"seller"})
              .queryParam("sort", new Object[]{"creationdate"})
              .queryParam("limit", new Object[]{150})
              .queryParam("offset", new Object[]{0})
              .queryParam("filter", new Object[]{"creationdate:[" + startDate + ".." + endDate + "]"})
              .queryParam("userid", new Object[]{userId});

...
}

...
}

class B {

   main(..) {
      Date endDate = new Date();
      Date startDate = new Date(endDate.getTime() - Duration.ofDays(30).toMillis());
      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());

      sDate = formatter.format(startDate);
      eDate = formatter.format(endDate);

      new A().apiCall(userId, sDate, eDate);

  }
      

}
```

And this above generates webTarget url as

```
JerseyWebTarget { https://svc1.abc.qa.def.com/svc/lookupservice/v2/findItems?userType=seller&sort=creationdate&limit=150&offset=0&filter=creationdate%3A%5B2022-03-08T15%3A26%3A35.951Z..2022-04-07T16%3A26%3A35.951Z%5D&userid=1005732584 }
```

It encodes `:[` in creation date.

How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out by not using webTarget's `.queryParams()` and instead passing URI with query.

```
String query = "?userType=seller&limit=25&offset=0&userid=" + userId + "&filter=creationdate:[" + startDate + ".." + endDate + "]";

URI uri = URI.create(endpoint + "/lookupservice/v2/findItems"+ query);

WebTarget webTarget = client.target(uri);
```